# How can I match either one pattern or another in Rosie?

Tags: rosie-pattern-language

How can I match one of two alternate patterns with Rosie Pattern Language?

For example if the string is "(248)" or "(313)" I want to match.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  Given those two specific patterns the expression would look like this:

```
eitherAreaCode = "(248)"/"(313)"
```

This would match either `(248)` or `(313)` and nothing else.